divergence of split sequences with $\sum a_i + \sum b_i = \infty \Rightarrow \sum x_i/(x_i^2 + 1) = \infty$
A given series $(x_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$, is split into $(a_i)$ and $(b_i)$ with $(x_i) = (a_i) \cup (b_i) ,$ such that $\lim a_i = \infty,$ and $\lim b_i = 0.$
If then $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}b_i = \infty $, then follows $\rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_i}{x_i^2 + 1} = \infty.$
I got this from a research paper. So far, I proved the other direction, which was easy, but this problem confuses me a bit, I didn't meet this splitting-type of problems.

By $(x_i) = (a_i) \cup (b_i)$, do you mean $x_i=a_i+b_i$, or something else?

No, I mean that the sequence elements are split, some are put in the first sequence, some in the other.

@JohnBlue I think it is better that you roll back the changes to your question, so the answer makes sense, and ask a new question with the corrected errors, which you link to this question, as suggested here. If you decide to keep this question edited, then you should also edit the title, as you have not updated it yet.

Thanks you zetko for your reply! I will undo it, then your answer and the question makes more sense!

This implication is false:
Take for example $a_n=n^2, b_n=-\frac{1}{n^2}$ and $$x_n=\begin{cases}a_k&\text{if $n=2k-1$}\\b_{k} &\text{if $n=2k$}\end{cases}$$
So the sequence is $1^2,-\frac{1}{1^2},2^2,-\frac{1}{2^2}\dots$
Clearly $\sum a_n = \infty$, so $\sum a_n + \sum b_n = \infty$, and $\lim a_n = \infty$ and $\lim b_n = 0$.
For even lengths, the sum \begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty \text{ even}} \frac{x_n}{x_n^2+1}&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{x_{2k-1}} {x_{2k-1}^2+1} + \frac{x_{2k}}{x_{2k}^2+1} \\&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k}{a_k^2+1} + \frac{b_k}{b_k^2+1} \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{1+k^4}-\frac{1/k^2}{1+{(-1/k^2)}^2} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{k^2}{1+k^4}-\frac{k^2}{k^4+1} = 0,
\end{align}
additionaly for odd lengths we observe the remaining term is $\leq \frac{k^2}{k^4+1}$, which goes to zero as $n$ goes to infinity. This is in contradiction to your statement.

Oh wow, but it must be true... maybe I did some error in restating it here. I will check your counter example first and then check again. Thank you very much for your effort!

You are right. I found the error, I am sorry..... :-((
I updated the question, but maybe I should have left it unchanged.... you got a great answer for a mistyped question.... hmm, what you think zetko?

Btw, if you live near Bavaria, I would happily spend you some beer sth., I first wanted to take a screenshot of the question from the paper, and then thought, I better type it... :-((
